# Pintersest Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /vendor/hansott/pinterest-php/src/Pinterest/Http/BuzzClient.php on line 71

Tags: php, pinterest

I have installed the PHP Pinterest API on my server and I have authenticated the user using OAuth. When I am trying to get board details I am facing an issue

> "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   /vendor/hansott/pinterest-php/src/Pinterest/Http/BuzzClient.php on
>   line 71". I have debugged the issue and found that the key
>   "Pinterest-Generated-By" doesn't have the value. For this please refer
>   Line number 71 in
>   /vendor/hansott/pinterest-php/src/Pinterest/Http/BuzzClient.php

Line cauisng issue,

```
list($key, $value) = explode(': ', $header);
```

My code:

```
$client = new Pinterest\Http\BuzzClient();

$auth = Pinterest\Authentication::onlyAccessToken($client, $token);
$api = new Pinterest\Api($auth);

$response = $api->getUserBoards();
```

Please let me know why I am facing this issue. And do I need to add value in settings to get the value for "Pinterest-Generated-By"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In /vendor/hansott/pinterest-php/src/Pinterest/Http/BuzzClient.php file, just replace:

```
list($key, $value) = explode(': ', $header);
```

with the lines below:

```
$parts = explode(': ', $header);

if (count($parts) !== 2) {
   $headers[$parts[0]] = '';
   continue;
}

list ($key, $value) = $parts;
```

And It will work fine. Actually, this has been fixed in the recent [commit](https://github.com/hansott/pinterest-php/commit/72a072c7f5b3c8ff01aa57631cfd9629dc0fe183).